# how do i make the numbered keyboard come up when user taps on a UITextField swift 5 iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
@IBOutlet weak var billTextField: UITextField!
```

how would i make this so when a user taps on the textfield, that the number keyboard appears on screen so the user can type a number / Float type number.

ie tip calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first got to your storyBoard and then click on your textfield and then go to show the attributes inspector and then change your keyboard in keyboard type you can see in below image [image: select keyboard type]

and you can also do with code :-

```
    self.your text name.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use third-party libraries for this available on GitHub. 
Like, NumericKeyboard or NumberKeyboard. Sharing link below:-

https://github.com/marcjordant/NumericKeyboard